# Query regarding Reported/Desired states of Device Twins@IOTHub

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am trying to implement a cloud based solution for Home Automation devices and exploring various options offered by Azure IOT Hub and device twins. Its in this context I need to understand few things :-

1)When a device sends reported properties update to IOTHub, is it mandatory for the back end application to simultaneously update desired properties update back to device of same properties. 
2)Do the Desired properties/Reported properties always remain to be in sync with each other - update on one(by either side) triggering update of another. so if cloud back end app updates desired properties to device, is it required for the device to update its properties and trigger back reported properties update back to IOTHub with same properties? 
3)In short can Reported and Desired properties ***be different at any point of time***?

Going through the documentation I understand that reported/desired properties at cloud end(and device end) can be different as these server different purpose. But it would be good if I get clarification on same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's entirely possible that Desired and Reported properties can be different at points in time. The idea behind Desired Properties is that is what you **want** the device properties to be, and you compare those to what the device is reporting.

For example, I could have a device that is looking for changes in a **currentColor** desired property to drive the color of an onboard LED. The device would see the change in the desired property, change the color of the LED and report that **currentColor** back to the cloud. The cloud could look for the reported color to be a specific color (let's say '*blue*') and could change the desired property for **currentColor** to be '*off*', which the device would then know to turn off the LED.

I don't believe it is mandatory for either the device-side or cloud-side to update Desired/Reported properties when a change is made (on either side). It all depends on your scenario.

Hope that helps!